# Why is the ObservableList underlined?

Tags: javafx

I'm new to JavaFX. I'm learning JavaFX on my own. I'm using Eclipse to run my codes. I learnt that the getChildren() method of the Group class gives you an object of the ObservableList class which holds the nodes. But the ObservableList is underlined in yellow in Eclipse and I cannot run my code. I'm just trying to create a very simple Application using JavaFX

This is my code

```
{
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Text welcome = new Text("Welcome To JavaFX");
        welcome.setFont(new Font(45));
        welcome.setX(45);
        welcome.setX(150);

        Group Root = new Group(welcome);
        ObservableList list = Root.getChildren();
        list.add(welcome);

        Scene scene = new Scene(Root,600,300);
        scene.setFill(Color.GREY);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample Application");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: Picture of my Code underlined in Yellow]

Comment: Probably because you only add to the list and never use it. It depends on the IDE you are using. Have you tried clicking on or hovering over the underlined word? It will normally tell you.

Comment: I tried it says "ObservableList is a raw type. References to generic type ObservableList<E> should be parameterized". Couldn't solve it from there

Comment: then it's time to read and understand some basic tutorial on generics :) And unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: That basically means you need to say what type of objects the list will be holding. Example `ObservableList<String>` or `ObservableList<Node>`.

Comment: This shouldn't prevent your program from working though: It's just a warning that could be ignored (but should be fixed by adding the type parameter). If your program does not run, there is an unrelated issue somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done there is using Java's automatic type erasure.

ObservableList is defined as:

`public interface ObservableList<E> extends List<E>, Observable {`

The `<E>` being the generic type of the elements. So if you have an ObservableList holding Nodes as is the case for you it would be:

`ObservableList<Node> foo = Root.getChildren()`

Your IDE is telling you that by leaving out the type parameter out you're essentially having an `ObservableList<Object>` which isn't an error but probably not what you want in this case.